# Setting a description with quick.db

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

In my discord bot , I want all users to have a customizable profile. Whenever they run a command !profile or !p , the bot will display an embed with bio (which is like an introduction like "Hello World" or something) , custom embed color of their choice and other database information (.ie coins, energy etc.) . I want to make sure that whenever they run something like !desc Hello World , their profile embed will have the message Hello World, and if they run !desc Lorem another time, their custom embed's bio will be edited to Lorem and so on. I got them implement with simple db.get and db.set function using quick.db but the problem is whenever the user sets a description with more than one arguments like **Hello World** , it only appears on the embed as **HelloWorld** but not the actual correct one with spaces. I really want the embed to display exactly what the user sets its description (with spaces and stuffs ) but currently my code isn't capable of it. Please give it a look and point out where I should change!

```
const db = require("quick.db");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  commands: ["description", "desc"],
  minArgs: 1,
  maxArgs: null,
  expectedArgs: ["description to add"],

  callback: (message, arguments, text) => {
    var desc;
    desc = arguments.join("");
    let tester = db.get(`_desc${message.author.id}`);

    if (!tester) {
      db.set(`_desc${message.author.id}`, desc);
    } else {
      db.delete(`_desc${message.author.id}`), db.set(`_desc${message.author.id}`, desc);
    }
    console.log(desc);
  },
};
```

The above is the code for !desc and the below is the one for !profile.

```
const db = require("quick.db");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  commands: ["profile", "p"],
  alias: ["p"],
  minArgs: 0,
  maxArgs: null,

  callback: async (message, arguments, text) => {
    let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.author;

    const balance = db.get(`honey_${target.id}`);
    const energy = db.get(`energy_${target.id}`);
    var desc = db.get(`_desc${target.id}`);
    if (desc === null) {
      let desc = "this user have yet to set a description!";
    }

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${target.tag}'s profile`)
      .setColor("#ECB802")
      .addFields(
        { name: "Description", value: `${desc}`, inline: false },
        {
          name: "cards",
          value: "1",
          inline: true,
          //to do
        },
        { name: "Gym battle record", value: "1/0", inline: true }, //to do
        {
          name: "Honey",
          value: `${balance} :honey_pot:`,
          inline: true,
        },
        {
          name: "energy",
          value: `${energy} :dizzy:`,
          inline: true,
        },
      );

    message.channel.send(embed);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `arguments.join('')` to get the description, which will join two strings with an empty string:

```js
const message = ['Hello', 'World'];

console.log(message.join('')); // no spaces
console.log(message.join(' ')); // instead, join by a space!
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing that one! It works now!

Comment: Glad I could help